# Confused by output using xargs

Tags: unix, command-line, xargs

I have these files in a directory:  y y1 y2 y3

Running this command:
`ls y* | xargs -i basename {}|xargs -i sed "s/{}//g"`

produces this:
1
2
3

Can someone explain why?!  I expected it to produce nothing - running sed four times, once for each file, and removing the file name each time. But actually it looks like it's applying sed with {} set to the first file, on a list of y1 y2 y3

This is Solaris 10

Comment: I *do* get nothing when running that command.

Comment: Me too - I get nothing. What unix are you using? Perhaps your xargs or sed is a bit different from your expectation - differences btwn GNU and POSIX still exist.

Comment: Oh dear, this is the 2nd question in a row that highlights a difference between Solaris and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try this on my linux box, I get inconsistent results.  Sometimes 123, sometimes (most of the times) 23, sometimes 12.  This is a subtle buffering race condition between the rightmost `xargs` and any of the `sed` it spawns.

Dissecting the command line:

- `ls y*` will output 4 lines, y, y1, y2 and y3; buffering not relevant
- `xargs -i basename {}` will read them and launch, in a sequence, `basename y`, `basename y1`, `basename y2`, `basename y3`; output, same as input in our case, is line-buffered as each line comes from a different process.
- `xargs -i sed "s/{}//g"`, for each line X it reads (more on that later), launches `sed "s/X//g"`
- each `sed "s/X//g"` filters out each X it sees in the lines it reads

Where it gets tricky: the last two commands read input from the same stream.  That stream is produced by multiple different processes in a sequence.  Depending on a multitude of factors (system load, scheduling), the output could come out in very different timing patterns.

Let's suppose they're all very fast.  Then all four lines might be available for the right `xargs` to read in a single block.  In that case, there would no input left for any of the `sed`s to read, hence **no output at all**.

On the other hand, if they were very slow, there might be only one line available for the right `xargs` on its first read attempt.  That line would be "y".  `xargs` would spawn the first `sed` as `sed "s/y//g"`, which would consume all remaining input (y1, y2, y3), strip `y`'s, and **output 1, 2, 3**.  Here's the same explanation again, with more explicit sequencing.

1. first `basename` writes "y".
2. right `xargs` reads "y", spawns `sed s/y//g`. `xargs` now waits for `sed` to complete.
3. second `basename` writes "y1"; `sed` reads "y1", writes "1"
4. third `basename` writes "y2";  `sed` reads "y2", writes "2"
5. fourth `basename` writes "y3"; `sed` reads "y3", writes "3"
6. left `xargs` is done; `sed` reads EOF and stops
7. right `xargs` tries to continue, reads EOF and stops

Not sure about my 12 case.  Possibly GNU `xargs` doesn't wait for its children to complete before it reads subsequent available input, and snatched the "y3" line from the first `sed`.

In any case, you just set up a pipeline with **multiple concurrent readers on the same writer**, which yields mostly undeterministic results.  **To be avoided.**

If you wanted operation on each of the files, it would be avoided by specifying a filename to use by `sed` (note the final {}):

```
ls y* | xargs -i basename {} | xargs -i sed "s/{}//g" {}
```

If what you wanted was a cross-product-type result (strip each file name from each file), you'd need to arrange to have the file list produced as many times as there are files.  Plus one for `xargs`, if you still used that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sed "s/{}//g" {} will run sed on the actual files - not just the filenames. Not sure that's what the op wanted though.

But yes, you're right - sed gets chained, reading from the same filedescriptor and you'll defintly have a subtle race.

Comment: good grief, that's even more confusing. I need to study this - your initial explanation is what I originally thought, but the race I don't quite get. NB the original intention of the coder (not me) was to produce the output as is (1 2 3). I just think it's happened by accident rather than design, and the code should certainly change to something more maintainable!

Answer (score 2):

The input to the `xargs` `-i` `sed`... command is:

```
y
y1
y2
y3
```

The command will read the line `y` and execute `sed` `s/y//g`, which reads from the standard input.  The standard input is inherited so it will have the same pipe as its standard input, and may be able to read the remaining input:

```
y1
y2
y3
```

The command `sed s/y//g` will remove the `y` from each line:

```
1
2
3
```

However if `xargs` consumes all the input before the first `sed` command is executed then the `sed` command will no have input left to read, and will do nothing.